# How to make a raw event run only once

Tags: discord.js

I have a raw event:

```js
this.on('raw', packet => {
            if (!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(packet.t)) return;
            const channel = this.channels.cache.get(packet.d.channel_id);
            if (channel.messages.cache.has(packet.d.message_id)) return;
            channel.messages.fetch(packet.d.message_id).then(message => {
                const emoji = packet.d.emoji.id ? `${packet.d.emoji.name}:${packet.d.emoji.id}` : packet.d.emoji.name;
                const reaction = message.reactions.cache.get(emoji);
                if (reaction) reaction.users.cache.set(packet.d.user_id, this.users.cache.get(packet.d.user_id));
                if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
                    this.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, this.users.cache.get(packet.d.user_id));
                }
                if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE') {
                    this.emit('messageReactionRemove', reaction, this.users.cache.get(packet.d.user_id));
                }
            });
        });
```

This event spams continuously when one reaction is added, I want to make it so if you react it will run once. How can I do this?

Comment: Make sure you do not have multiple Events in each other!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the raw event past discord.js version 12. As there are some issues when your bot grows.

Instead use Partials as explained in the offical Discord.js Guide

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    // When we receive a reaction we check if the reaction is partial or not
    if (reaction.partial) {
        // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed the fetching might result in an API error, which we need to handle
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            // Return as `reaction.message.author` may be undefined/null
            return;
        }
    }
    // Now the message has been cached and is fully available
    console.log(`${reaction.message.author}'s message "${reaction.message.content}" gained a reaction!`);
    // The reaction is now also fully available and the properties will be reflected accurately:
    console.log(`${reaction.count} user(s) have given the same reaction to this message!`);
});
```

Source and more information: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages